# How to get next user id?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying print two rows, this is code for the first next user, first with next five users and second with next 25 users after 5, I am getting an error while getting next id

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY  id  ASC ");

 while($auto_inc_result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
     $last_id = $auto_inc_result['id'];
 }

 $next_id = ($last_id+1);

 echo $next_id;
```

I tried this also but it didn't work also

```
SELECT * 
FROM User 
WHERE id>$_SESSION['id'] 
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: I don't answer questions with the word 'wanna' in them, but as an aside, be aware that your API is insecure and was deprecated several years ago.

Comment: @Strawberry Is id integer?

Comment: @Strawberry I have edited question, please take a look, I tried but it didn't work `SELECT * FROM User WHERE id>$_SESSION['id'] ORDER by id ASC LIMIT 25`

Comment: Saying _“I am getting an error”_ without mentioning what exactly that error is, is really not clever; plus this seems to be rather a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56030658/how-to-print-next-25-users-who-signed-up-after-current-user to begin with.

Comment: Whatever it is that you're actually trying to do, this seems like a terrible idea. :-(

Answer (score -1):

Dont calculate you next value in PHP, because your value is calculated in database side.

Use this query:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "yourDatabaseName"
AND TABLE_NAME = "yourTableName"
```